# Reflection For Static Class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, static

I have created a Static Class and used that in Reflection.
But when i accessed the Methods of that class, its showing 5 methods but i have created only 1.
The extra methods are

```
Write
ToString
Equals
GetHashCode
GetType
```

But i have created only the Write methods.

One static methods can be in a static class but these extra 4 methods are not statics and from where they have drived. What is the base class for that

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Reflection;

namespace ReflectionDemo
{
    static class ReflectionTest
    {
        public static int Height;
        public static int Width;
        public static int Weight;
        public static string Name;

        public static void Write()
        {
            Type type = typeof(ReflectionTest);         //Get type pointer
            FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields();      //obtain all fields
            MethodInfo[] methods = type.GetMethods();
            Console.WriteLine(type);
            foreach (var item in methods)
            {
                string name = item.Name;
                Console.WriteLine(name);
            }

            foreach (var field in fields)
            {
                string name = field.Name; //(null); //Get value
                object temp = field.GetValue(name);
                if (temp is int) //see if it is an integer
                {
                    int value = (int)temp;
                    Console.Write(name);
                    Console.Write("(int) = ");
                    Console.WriteLine(value);
                }
                else if (temp is string)
                {
                    string value = temp as string;
                    Console.Write(name);
                    Console.Write("(string) = ");
                    Console.WriteLine(value);
                }
            }
        }        
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ReflectionTest.Height = 100;
            ReflectionTest.Width = 50;
            ReflectionTest.Weight = 300;
            ReflectionTest.Name = "Perl";

            ReflectionTest.Write();

            Console.ReadLine();            
        }
    }
}
```

But how to create an object of a static class to access those methods
static class cannot have non static methods

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Every type in C# inherits (directly, or indirectly) from  `System.Object`. Thus inheriting `Object`'s methods `ToString`, `GetHashCode`, `Equals` and `GetType`. That is why you are seeing them while exploring all methods of `ReflectionTest` type object. To get only static methods use this `BindingFlags` enum member:

```
type.GetMethods(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static)
```

Comment: But i am not able to get those method from my class like we get for Static class 'ReflectionTest.GetType()'

Comment: And we cannot also create a object for Static class. and how come not static members can be inherited in Static Class

Comment: Right, that is because these methods are not static. However you are exploring the Type object, and you see both static and not-static methods.

Comment: then how to access those methods

Comment: These methods do not belong to the `ReflectionTest` class in any way. These are the methods of `Type type = typeof(ReflectionTest)` object that you are creating. They do not exist in a context of `ReflectionTest` class, and you cannot access them from it at all. `Write` method is totally a different story - it is a part of `ReflectionTest` declaration, and you can access it as simply as `ReflectionTest.Write`.

Comment: if my class cannot access those method, then why this type.GetMethods() showing those method name

Comment: Because this is not the class that you are exploring - this is the reflection object of class `Type` that represents your class `ReflectionTest`. Besides information about your class it also contains common information (including methods) all objects contain.

Answer (score 28):

Only static members can be *declared* in a static class - but as far as the CLR is concerned, it's just another class, which happens to only have static members, doesn't have a constructor, and is both abstract and sealed. The CLR doesn't have the *concept* of a static class... so the class still inherits the instance members from `object`.

This is a good example of why it's important to distinguish between *language* features, *framework* features and *runtime* features.

Comment: Since an abstract class cannot be sealed, this should detect a static class `type.IsClass && type.IsAbstract && type.IsSealed`

Answer (score 3):

Those other methods are inherited from the [`Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) base class.

Pass `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` to `GetMethods()` to elide inherited methods.

Answer (score 1):

These methods are derived from the `object` class from which all classes natively derive.

Answer (score 1):

All these "additional" methods come from [object (alias)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kkx3h3c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)/[Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), the base class everything in C#.
Here's the quote:

*In the unified type system of C#, all types, predefined and user-defined, reference types and value types, inherit directly or indirectly from Object.*

Answer (score 1):

When using BindingFlags you must explicitly specify the desired method flags:

```
type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
```

Answer (score 0):

You see `Object` methods (even if not static). To restrict your method list you should specify you want only static methods using `BindingFlags.Static` It doesn't matter your class is marked as static, I guess for compatibility reasons with first .NET versions that modifier is only for compilers (you can't create an instance and so on).

Answer (score 0):

Static classes inherit from `System.Object`, and that's where you get these methods from. You can look at `MethodInfo.DeclaringType` to check.